# Looping trough a protected SendinBlue object

Tags: php, codeigniter, sendinblue

i have succesfully integrated the SendinBlue v3 API into my codeigniter application, but for some reason i'm unable to loop trough the results when using the API.

When i var_dump, my object looks like this :

```
 object(SendinBlue\Client\Model\GetEmailCampaigns)#110 (1) {
      ["container":protected]=>
      array(2) {
        ["campaigns"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          array(23) {
            ["id"]=>
            int(2)
            ["name"]=>
            string(12) "Testcampagne"
            ["type"]=>
    .....
```

Since the root object is protected , i'm not able to loop trough this to see my campaigns.
I was able to read it by converting it to an array  , $result = (array)$result;
and then i had to use

```
foreach ($result as $campaigns)
{
    foreach ($campaigns as $campaignh)
    {
         foreach ((array)$campaignh as $campaign)
         {
             echo $campaign['status'];
....
```

I'm sure there must be a way to loop trough the campaigns in one single foreach? Feeling really stupid about this!

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
$data = (array) $OBJECTfromSendInBlue;
$keys=array_keys(       $data);  
//print_r(  $keys   );
$contacts=$data[    $keys[0]];
print_r($contacts);
```

then you can easily loop $contacts.
;-)

Comment: It's a strange way of managing objects in php but I have to say that it works, ...and at the moment it seems to be the only solution because I haven't found any indication in the official Brevo documentation...